# Let $W$ be finite dim. Prove there are not subspaces $U$ and $V$ of $W$ such that $U\cap V=\{0\}$ and $\dim U+\dim V>\dim W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $W$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. Prove there are no two subspaces $U$ and $V$ of $W$ such that $U\cap V=\{0\}$ and $\dim U+\dim V>\dim W$.

This is from a practice exam.

We are using Gallian's algebra text, so we don't have any linear algebra theorems to appeal to except the invariance of basis size. I am trying a build a nonzero vector in the intersection of U and V, perhaps by using the the vectors from the bases of U and V out together in one set, which has to be dependent. Does this sound promising? The hints bellows are generous, but I don't have those theorems to work with.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: We are using Gallian's algebra text, so I only have a few definitions and the invariance of the basis size to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Suppose that $U \cap V = 0$. Prove that if $\{u_1,\dots,u_m\}$ is a basis of $U$ and $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, then
$$
\{u_1,\dots,u_m,v_1,\dots,v_n\}
$$
is linearly independent and actually is a basis for $U+V$.

Alternatively, suppose that $m+n>\dim W$. Then the above set is linearly dependent, which means that you find coefficients not all zero such that
$$
a_1u_1+\dots+a_mu_m+b_1v_1+\dots+b_nv_n=0
$$
Consider
$$
w=a_1u_1+\dots+a_mu_m=-(b_1v_1+\dots+b_nv_n)
$$
Then $w\ne0$ and…

Comment: This sounds promising. I was finding it difficult to construct a vector in the intersection. I'm assuming you mean V rather than W, right?

Comment: @OLP I added a different way

Comment: Thanks, I got there but couldn't also get the vector in U. I can see how to get a different nonzero vector in U. But I am thinking I need to get one in both U and V for a contradiction.

Comment: I think I see it, now. The same vector is nonzero in both sets already. Excellent.

Comment: But to prove each side is nonzero, I guess an a separate proof by contradiction is necessary, depending on the dimensions of the two subspaces.    No, if one side equals zero, they both do, contradicting dependence. I think I see the entire proof now. Thanks for this specialized approach.

Comment: @OLP Since *at least* one of the coefficients is nonzero, it's either some $a_i$ or some $b_i$. Therefore $v\ne0$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\dim(U+V)=\dim U+\dim V-\dim(U\cap V)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Consider the linear mapping:

\begin{align*} \varphi\colon  U\times V&\rightarrow U+V\\
(u,v)&\mapsto u-v
\end{align*} 
What is its kernel? What is it isomorphic to? Try to apply the rank nullity theorem to $\varphi$.